# Can someone explain Git Bash CLI Not Showing Characters Properly?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a problem with command line. It's showing weird characters. Following is the example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running git bash inside of another terminal? This seems to be an issue with the way cmd.exe or whatever its called cant display these colorchars (are they called this way?) properly. Maybe try the new windows terminal

Comment: Yes, I have installed GitBash on windows, seems like this issue is when I am using GitBAsh command line. When I use normal windows CLI then this issue doesn't appear.